# java.lang.NullPointerException in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I had a Spark/Kafka streaming application. The application would interact with oracle database for storing offsets and saving some data.

After several hours of successful streaming, app is failing with the following error.

[image]

Can i know what could cause these errors in Spark-Kafka streaming application.

This is what i can see from logs..

```
Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.

2017/01/05 21:14:00 ERROR JobScheduler: Error in job generator
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeRdd(BlockManagerMaster.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.unpersistRDD(SparkContext.scala:1612)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.unpersist(RDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$clearMetadata$3.apply(DStream.scala:469)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$clearMetadata$3.apply(DStream.scala:468)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:107)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:107)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2.foreach(HashMap.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.clearMetadata(DStream.scala:468)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$clearMetadata$5.apply(DStream.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$clearMetadata$5.apply(DStream.scala:481)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.clearMetadata(DStream.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$clearMetadata$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$clearMetadata$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:127)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.clearMetadata(DStreamGraph.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.clearMetadata(JobGenerator.scala:261)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Driver Log reports these errors

```
    2017/01/06 16:34:03 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 18
    2017/01/06 16:34:13 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 22
    2017/01/06 16:34:23 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 20
```

Nothing weird from Master log.

```
17/01/06 17:05:38 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20170105220118-0005/34944 because it is EXITED
17/01/06 17:05:38 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170105220118-0005/34947 on worker worker-20170105215345-10.251.228.107-53462
17/01/06 17:05:43 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20170105220118-0005/34945 because it is EXITED
17/01/06 17:05:43 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170105220118-0005/34948 on worker worker-20170105215335-10.251.228.103-28641
17/01/06 17:05:44 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20170105220118-0005/34947 because it is EXITED
17/01/06 17:05:44 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170105220118-0005/34949 on worker worker-20170105215345-10.251.228.107-53462
17/01/06 17:05:46 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20170105220118-0005/34946 because it is EXITED
17/01/06 17:05:46 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170105220118-0005/34950 on worker worker-20170105215332-10.251.228.102-23104
```

Comment: What does the master log look like?

Comment: thank for responding...I have updated the post with the prices of driver and master logs. All of my other apps with similar functionality are running fine...

Comment: Do you have any broadcast variables?

Comment: I don't have any broadcast with this application..But the driver log is showing this error..And i am not controlling any cleaning related parameters.  Our spark version is 1.6.1